# Getting your Flattr transactions from within a python script?

Tags: python, flattr

I'm trying to get my flattr transactions CSV files from within a python script (see http://ploum.net/post/flattrstat ).

From the webinterface, a CSV link look like:
https://flattr.com/transaction/view/id/$RANDOM_NUMBER/format/csv

So, in order to achieve what I want, I only need:

1) To authenticate myself on Flattr through the python script (no idea how to do that). Is there any python library recommended?

2) To understand the logic behind $RANDOM_NUMBER or to have a way to get it. (in further evolution of my script, I want to be able to define a start date and a end date you want to download. It will allows people to make statistic on a specific date range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random number as you call it is the transaction id. There is no way to guess or calculate what the id will be. There is also no way to ask for the id (like through an api)
but you could scrape it from your transaction list (https://flattr.com/dashboard/transactions) if you manage to login first.

There's currently no simple way to do what you want since transaction information is not exposed through the API. We might add this later but for the time being you will have to make due with scraping the transaction list.

Comment: I know from experience that scrapping sucks. Will not lose time with that.