# See how much was donated to a particular Thing

Tags: flattr

Say you want to have a kickstarter-like site using Flattr, where you create a Thing for each individual user. How would you be able to tell (with the API) how much each user Flattr'd? It wouldn't update right away (it would have to update at the first of each month), but would it be possible at all? If there's no way to do this, could you tell how much a particular Flattr'd to you in total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the details of each months revenue reports there's a link to download that revenue report as a CSV-file which you could then import into your system to find out how much each thing has received. The information is not yet exposed through the API (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047968/getting-your-flattr-transactions-from-within-a-python-script)) so you would have to download the files manually - luckily there's only twelve months a year so it's not too much work to do :)

The CSV-file contains these columns:

- period - Date in the format of YYYY-MM
- id - The internal numeric id of the flattr thing
- flattr url - The URL to the thing on Flattr.com
- url - The original URL that the thing is pointing to
- title
- clicks - The amount of clicks for the thing during the period
- revenue - The revenue for the thing during the period
- clicks total

So - as you see you can't see how much each individual click has been worth if a thing has received more than one click and you can't either see which users it is that has clicked the thing (you can however see some of the users by [asking the regular API](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/#the-thing-object) for more information, but since some users are anonymous you can't figure out who they are without asking them for permission to do so).

If you really need to know if a user has flattred something, then you can force them to [flattr the thing through your system](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-url) by having them [authenticate with your system](http://developers.flattr.net/api/#authorization) using the [Flattr API](http://developers.flattr.net/api/) - that way you will at least know if a flattr has been made by the user or not, but you will still have trouble trying to figure out how much their flattrs are worth - but that's kind of the point with Flattr - that people should spend whatever they personally feel comfortable with rather than spending what others think they should be spending.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was pretty much perfect.